# Get запрос, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

Моя страница состоит из запроса 20?page=2 (к примеру).
Как мне при нажатие на определенную кнопку, сделать увеличения на 1. (Событие уже сделал). Благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 1):

[URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

```js
let url = new URL(location.href);
let page = url.searchParams.get('page') |0;
url.searchParams.set('page', ++page);

// location.href = url.href

console.log(url.href);

url.searchParams.set('page', ++page);
console.log(url.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var params = window
    .location
    .search
    .replace('?','')
    .split('&')
    .reduce(
        function(p,e){
            var a = e.split('=');
            p[ decodeURIComponent(a[0])] = decodeURIComponent(a[1]);
            return p;
        },
        {}
    );

console.log( params['data']); //вытаскивает параметр data
```

после вам нужно увеличить параметр на 1, и сделать обратное действие (т е собрать строку)

Comment: как суперглобал пхп поможет в решении задачи с лейбой `js`

Comment: оу, извеняюсь, сглупил и уже поправил